# Recommendation on how to convert my horizontal Navbar into a Curtain Overlay on mobile?

Tags: html, css, navbar, overlay

I have a functional Navbar that I am currently satisfied with, however, I don't like how it stacks on smaller screens. So I have decided to have it convert into a curtain overlay with a menu button. However, I seem to be having a slight issue I haven't figured out.

1. [Navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyRf9.png) appears on all devices still.
2. [Mobile Navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hdg0k.png) (curtain overlay) doesn't appear on smaller screens.
3. Navbar does not disappear as intended on smaller screens.

### What I Tried

I have adjusted the code many times in many different combinations after referencing materials online, but I can't quite get it to work the way I'm wanting. Perhaps I'm overlooking something?

1. Placing the `<img>` and `<span>` elements outside of the `<div>` container will allow the Mobile Navbar to show simultaneously with the Navbar, albeit erroneously, and function.
2. Using `.className {display: none}` did hide the Navbar on Mobile but not on Desktop when used in conjunction with `@media screen ... { .navbar {display: none;} .overlay-content {display: inline-block;} }`.

### What I Expected

When on desktop devices (or devices with larger screens) the normal navigation bar will show.
When on mobile devices and tablets the navigation bar is removed and is replaced with a curtain overlay using either/both `<img class="navi">` and `<span class="navi">` elements to display the overlaid menu. The `<img>` element should retain the `sticky` attribute.

##### The below code snippets shows where I finally ended up before seeking help:

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("sideNav").style.width = "100%";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("sideNav").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
/*//////////[ Sticky NavBar ]//////////*/


/* Toggles between relative and fixed, depending on the scroll position. It is positioned relative until a given offset position is met in the viewport - then it "sticks" in place (like position:fixed). The sticky value is not supported in IE or Edge 15 and earlier versions. However, for these versions the navbar will inherit default position */

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #3586ff;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  font-size: medium;
}


/* Top Navigation Bar Link Style */

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar a.right {
  float: right;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #3586ff;
  color: black;
}

.navbar a.active {
  background-color: #3586ff;
  color: white;
}


/*//////////[ Sticky NavBar ]//////////*/


/*//////////[ Mobile NavBar ]//////////*/


/* The Overlay (background) */

.overlay {
  /* Height & width depends on how you want to reveal the overlay (see JS below) */
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Black fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  /* Black w/opacity */
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}


/* Position the content inside the overlay */

.overlay-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}


/* The navigation links inside the overlay */

.overlay a {
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}


/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */

.overlay a:hover,
.overlay a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}


/* Position the close button (top right corner) */

.overlay .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 45px;
  font-size: 60px;
}


/* When the height of the screen is less than 450 pixels, change the font-size of the links and position the close button again, so they don't overlap */

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay a {
    font-size: 20px
  }
  .overlay .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
  }
}

img.navi {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 60px;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

span.navi {
  top: 0;
  font-size: medium;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*//////////[ Mobile NavBar ]//////////*/
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="navbar">
    <a type="text/html" href="/html/home.html" target="_parent">Home</a>
    <a type="text/html" href="/html/join.html" target="_parent">Join Us!</a>
    <a type="text/html" href="#" class="active">Chat Room</a>
    <a type="text/html" href="/html/showings.html" target="_parent">Showings</a>
    <a type="text/html" href="/html/gamerooms.html" target="_parent">Game Rooms</a>
    <a type="text/html" href="/html/openforuse.html" target="_parent">Open Link</a>
    <a type="text/html" href="/html/login.html" target="_parent" class="right">Login</a>
  </div>
  <div id="sideNav" class="overlay">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <div class="overlay-nav">
      <a type="text/html" href="/html/home.html" target="_parent">Home</a>
      <a type="text/html" href="/html/join.html" target="_parent">Join Us!</a>
      <a type="text/html" href="#" class="active">Chat Room</a>
      <a type="text/html" href="/html/showings.html" target="_parent">Showings</a>
      <a type="text/html" href="/html/gamerooms.html" target="_parent">Game Rooms</a>
      <a type="text/html" href="/html/openforuse.html" target="_parent">Open Link</a>
      <a type="text/html" href="/html/login.html" target="_parent" class="right">Login</a>
    </div>
    <img class="navi" src="/img/img/Navi.png" alt="Navi" onclick="openNav()" />
    <span class="navi" onclick="openNav()">Navigation</span>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="/js/mobile_menu.js"></script>
```

### Extra

<s>I have a [wave animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngkjy.png) for my footer that appears over the top of the curtain overlay. Anyway to prevent this without breaking the wave?</s>

`Edit:`
I had completely forgotten about the `z-index`:

```css
.object{z-index: 1001;}
```

Once I remembered it I was able to get the affect I wanted.


```css
/*//////////[ Footer ]//////////*/


/*///////[ Wave & NavBar ]//////*/


/* Provides a footer with a navbar. It includes links to other pages and to social media along with the site logo. */

.footer {
  position: relative;
  /* Specifies the type of positioning method used for an element (static, relative, fixed, absolute or sticky). */
  top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  /* Sets the width of an element. */
  background: #3586ff;
  min-height: 100px;
  /* Specifies the minimum height of an element. */
  padding: 20px 50px;
  display: flex;
  /* Defines a flex container; inline or block depending on the given value. It enables a flex context for all its direct children. */
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* Defines the direction of the flexible items. */
}

.social-icon,
.menu {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px 0;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* Specifies whether flex items are forced onto one line or can wrap onto multiple lines. */
}

.social-icon__item,
.menu__item {
  list-style: none
}

.social-icon__link {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 0.5s;
  /* Specifies the speed curve of the transition effect. */
}

.social-icon__link:hover {
  transform: translateY(-10px)
}

.menu__link {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 0.5s;
  /* Specifies the speed curve of the transition effect. */
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0.75;
  /* Sets the opacity level for an element. */
  font-weight: 300;
  /* Specifies the weight of a font. */
}

.menu__link:hover {
  opacity: 1
}

.footer p {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 15px 0 10px 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.wave {
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  left: 0;
  /* Specifies the left position of a positioned element. */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  /* Sets the height of an element. */
  background: url("https://i.ibb.co/wQZVxxk/wave.png");
  background-size: 1000px 100px;
  /* Specifies the size of the background images. */
}

.wave#wave1 {
  z-index: 1000;
  /* Specifies the stack order of an element. An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order. */
  opacity: 1;
  bottom: 0;
  /* Specifies the bottom position of a positioned element. */
  animation: animateWaves 4s linear infinite;
  /* Defines a CSS animation. */
}

.wave#wave2 {
  z-index: 999;
  opacity: 0.5;
  bottom: 10px;
  animation: animate 4s linear infinite !important;
}

.wave#wave3 {
  z-index: 1000;
  opacity: 0.2;
  bottom: 15px;
  animation: animateWaves 3s linear infinite;
}

.wave#wave4 {
  z-index: 999;
  opacity: 0.7;
  bottom: 20px;
  animation: animate 3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animateWaves {
  0% {
    background-position-x: 1000px
  }
  /* Specifies the starting position of an animation. */
  100% {
    background-positon-x: 0px
  }
  /* Specifies the ending position of an animation. */
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    background-position-x: -1000px
  }
  100% {
    background-positon-x: 0px
  }
}


/*///////[ Wave & NavBar ]//////*/


/*//////////[ Footer ]//////////*/
```

````html
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="waves">
    <div class="wave" id="wave1"></div>
    <div class="wave" id="wave2"></div>
    <div class="wave" id="wave3"></div>
    <div class="wave" id="wave4"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="/img/favicons/favicon.svg" alt="Logo" height="50" width="50" />
  </div>
  <ul class="social-icon">
    <li class="social-icon__item">
      <a title="Discord Link" class="social-icon__link" href="https://discord.gg/">
        <ion-icon name="logo-discord"></ion-icon>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="social-icon__item">
      <a title="FaceBook Link" class="social-icon__link" href="#">
        <ion-icon name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="social-icon__item">
      <a title="Twitter Link" class="social-icon__link" href="#">
        <ion-icon name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="social-icon__item">
      <a title="LinkedIn Link" class="social-icon__link" href="#">
        <ion-icon name="logo-linkedin"></ion-icon>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="social-icon__item">
      <a title="Instagram Link" class="social-icon__link" href="#">
        <ion-icon name="logo-instagram"></ion-icon>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="/html/home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="/html/welcome.html">About</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="/html/docs.html">Documents</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="/html/privacy.html">Privacy</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="/html/terms.html">Terms</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="/html/services.html">Services</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="mailto:someone">Contact GZ</a></li>
  </ul>
  <p>&copy;Company | All Rights Reserved</p>
</footer>

```
````